# Find non-ASCII line or character in file using Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, argparse

I am trying to write a script to find out which line in a file contains non ASCII-characters (specifically "windows-1252"). I have written this script in the hope that it would error when it reaches the line which contains the wrong character:

```
import argparse

FILE_ENCODING = "windows-1252"


def get_failed_character(filepath):
    with open(filepath, encoding=FILE_ENCODING) as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            try:
                line.strip()
            except:
                print(num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Parse file."
    )
    parser.add_argument("--file", help="File name")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    get_failed_character(args.file)
```

Comment: Your concept of "wrong character" is off. What does your input file look like, exactly, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting the script to error on the line which contains the non windows-1252 character, so that I can see which line it is on. I have added the file format to the question

Comment: And what's your question about that script? Anything not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, cp1252 is not a "form of ASCII", it's an ASCII superset, so you're really looking for non-cp1252 here.

The simplest solution here is to just use the `errors='replace'` mode, then search each line for the replacement character:

```
def get_failed_character(filepath):
    with open(filepath, encoding=FLOW_FILE_ENCODING, errors='replace') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if '\ufffd' in line:  # 0xFFFD is the Unicode replacement character
                print(num)
```

I will note that this is not a particularly safe way of checking; cp1252 has mappings for all but five possible bytes, so it's fairly *likely* that text in some other ASCII superset encoding will pass this test (it'll just produce gibberish for the bytes outside the ASCII range). This is why ASCII supersets (aside from UTF-8) are such a bad idea; without *knowing* the encoding ahead of time, you're likely to successfully decode the text to garbage, because most supersets can map data intended to be in one encoding to themselves without error, it's just gibberish to human beings. You need to *know* the *real* encoding, or you're just making bad guesses.

If your goal is to find the non-ASCII cp1252 characters (your question is worded a little unclearly), this will still work, just change the argument to `encoding='ascii'` so all non-ASCII becomes the replacement character.